# How to define an array of a type that includes a generic type variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following types in Typescript:

```
type Task<T> = () => Promise<T>;
type QueueItem<T> = { task: Task<T>; resolve: (v: T) => void; reject: () => any };
```

I have a class that uses these types:

```
class Queue {
  private queue: QueueItem<T>[] = [];
  insertTask<T>(task: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.queue.push({ task, resolve, reject });
    });
    return promise;
  }
}
```

Im trying to define a new type that is an array of `QueueItem<T>`. I have tried:

`queue = [] as QueueItem<T>[];`

`queue: QueueItem<T>[] = [];`

`queue<T>: QueueItem<T>[] = [];`

But none worked. I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)
```

How can I define it correctly?

You can try it in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-surf-w694o)

Comment: Not quite sure what `T` is supposed to represent in this case. Did you mean `class Queue<T>`? There is no point to having a generic property to a non generic class.

Comment: Just adding the method of the class that uses the array, not sure if it makes any difference. The syntax of `class Queue<T>` is strange, do I have to add every generic type variable that uses the class in the top of the class? :/

Comment: @Rashomon updated your defintion of `resolve`, it matters to the variance of `QueueItem` how `T` is used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a variable that is typed with an open type parameter. You can use `unknown` (if `T` is covariant), `never` (if `T` is contravariant) or `any` (works for `T` invariant or any other varinance but is less safe)

In your case `T` appears in both covariant (in `task`) and in a contravariant position (in position in `resolve`) so `any` is the only choice:

````
type Task<T> = () => Promise<T>;
type QueueItem<T> = { task: Task<T>; resolve: (v:T) => void; reject: () => any };


class Queue {
  private queue: QueueItem<any>[] = [];

  insertTask<T>(task: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    const promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.queue.push({ task, resolve, reject });
    });
    return promise;
  }
}```
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNYB4YD4oF4oAoCU2mACgE4D2AtgJYIRroDcAUKJFAIoCuEPAksAiUG2KAG8owREgBcsaQ0ZRSEBOQA2ANwhzcmmTEJZMm8tQAmSlQCsIAY2C6jmOADsQUAL4tmzO+sQETh4ecWYoKDBSak04QSgARxCdYN4IASEUNxB0AG0AXVEClgjwqGpXOlJgeGQGXClkJyIoMipaegx8OTaaOhExMoi7ckrgSIo+6BxXCAB3VsmO+twVNS0IABplCFsHZzCIo8kAC1oAOiS087AuBBPcCUakbbWNbVfd+3HPfBKj37-CIqYBcUiuCbtOj-TzMTxAA)

Since you are inserting many different `T` in `queue` there is no way to preserve the types off all of these. If you were to give all the tasks to ever be executed in the `Queue` constructor you could use a tuple type, but that seems to be antithetical to the point of the `Queue`.


Another option is to make `Queue` generic if you just need to forward the type parameter:


```ts
type Task<T> = () => Promise<T>;
type QueueItem<T> = { task: Task<T> };

class Queue<T> {
  private queue: QueueItem<T>[] = [
  ];
}
````

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNYB4YD4oF4oAoCU2mACgE4D2AtgJYIRroDcAUKJFAIoCuEPAksAiUG2KAG8owREgBcsaSIC+LZgGMANogScePEWOZQoYUtQBucQVACOuiHO68IAoQwDaAXVFvDUDy0VmIA)

Comment: @Rashomon The `unknown` solution holds, I would even advise against adding the `T` parameter in `insertTask` as that type info will be lost anyway and seems to serve no other purpose in the `insertTask` methods itself (it does not constrain any parameters or the return type in any way).

Comment: You are right. I was trying to generate a minimal example of my problem, and realized it wasnt the same (:facepalm:). I actually use `Promise<T>` for the return. I will upvote you, and... if you can check it again, it would very helpful :)

Comment: @Rashomon checked again, now `T` is indeed useful for the clients of `Queue`, but as to the internal representation of the queue, `any` becomes the only viable option (since `T` is now invariant for `QueueItem`. It appears both in a return type and and as a parameter to a function )

Answer (score 0):

The `Query` class is missing the `T` generic, so typescript do know of which type the queue items are.

```
class Queue<T> {
  private queue: QueueItem<T>[] = [];
}
```